# How to remove the border color from the drop down border-bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to remove the border color from the drop down `border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);`

**When I debugged I found its coming from this class MuiInput-underline-2593**

But the CSS class `MuiInput-underline-2593:before` is coming from the framework.

Can you guys tell me how to fix it. So that in future I can fix it myself.
Providing my relevant code snippet and sandbox link below

https://codesandbox.io/s/4x9lw9qrmx

```or-tag-here
MuiInput-underline-2593:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "\00a0";
    position: absolute;
    transition: border-bottom-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
    pointer-events: none;
}


<Select
    className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}
    classes={classes}
    styles={selectStyles}
    options={this.state.suggestions}
    components={components}
    value={this.state.single}
    onChange={this.handleChange("network")}
    placeholder="Search a to do"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own style/class to the element you need and set `border-bottom` rule with an `!important` suffix. This will override the rule from your framework.

```
.your-class{
   border-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: hey I updated your code in the sandbox but still I am seeing the bug, when I hover over drop down I see two different borders, is there anyway I can remove this border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42); completely, can you update in my sandbox its so confusing  https://codesandbox.io/s/4x9lw9qrmx

Comment: I'm not familiar with your library, it seems to generate a dynamic class name for each element and your elements doesn't have a static class I can use (also don't understand how to add one)

Comment: hey I looked into their api and applied disabled but still not working, can you help me, providing api links here https://material-ui.com/api/select/ https://material-ui.com/api/input/ disableUnderline={true}
              disabled={true}

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can just delete the whole CSS part it should be gone.

so your code would look like:

```
<Select
          className={classes.queryBuilderContainerItem}
          classes={classes}
          styles={selectStyles}
          options={this.state.suggestions}
          components={components}
          value={this.state.single}
          onChange={this.handleChange("network")}
          placeholder="Search a to do"
        />
```

Comment: hey i need some of the css in that, But the CSS class MuiInput-underline-2593:before is coming from the framework.

Comment: most all of that CSS is just for displaying that line correctly.. MuiInput-underline-2593:before *is* that line. The line would also be gone if you add a `border-bottom: 0`, like in @Itay-gal 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under the file named `AutoCompleteComponent.js` check `queryBuilderContainer` and comment or delete the border shown.

Hope this helps.